# What criteria is used to determine whether to refactor a code piece or not?

Tags: refactoring, communication

Refactoring code is usually a matter of applying better suiting patterns, applying coding conventions or improving performance. On the other hand, refactoring costs time and introduces the risk of including new bugs.

**What criteria should be used to determine whether to refactor a code unit or not?**

My guesses are:

- How good is the test coverage? The more of the code is covered, the lesser the possible side-effects of the refactoring.
- How critical is the code? The more important it is, the higher is the impact of bugs.
- How big is the gain of the refactoring? This seems highly subjective. Even where the reason is performance, the slower version might be better maintainable or easier to understand.

What other aspects need to be evaluated and is there a formula or system for determining this? I'm looking for scientific or at least systematic approaches.

**EDIT:** I think the question is a bit off of what I actually wanted to know. It's rather: Once you found a possible code smell, how do you prioritize and communicate it? What makes one refactoring more important/urgent than another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different situations and reasons when you should do refactoring. For example, your method is doing a lot of things. If method is doing a lot of things, it's very difficult to test it, so you need to break down into smaller and simpler methods.

Usually you should keep that one class is responsible only for one thing, and if it's not, then it's time for refactoring.

Also if method has a lot of parameters, then maybe your method is in a wrong class or maybe can be optimize on some other way.

If you have a lot of if-else conditions, then probably you should take some state/strategy pattern to eliminate if-else.

There are really a lot of cases where you should start doing refactoring, and the best is first to read the book Refactoring of Martin Fowler. In this book he covers a lot of situations and I would highly recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I think I didn't ask a clear question. Let me rephrase it: After you found a code smell, how do you decide whether to refactor it or not? How do you argue for a certain refactoring? I mean, in the same time you could have implemented features or fixed other code smells.

Comment: then definitely depends on the other tasks and priorities. Of course, the main priority should be tasks for fixing bugs and then others. If you need to choose between couple of different places to be refactored, you should  go with that one which is the most critical to be solved. Also if you need to implement new feature it would depend on how urgent is to implement that and then decide what to do. Unfortunately there is no right answer on your question, everything depends on situation, project, conditions, priorities and your feeling.

Comment: Thanks! "...which is the most critical to be solved" how do you know which is most critical when it comes to refactoring?

Comment: again depends :) Let's assume that you don't have bugs in the system and don't need to develop any new feature. You did checking your code and found couple of places which should be refactored. Usually the first one should be if you find repeating code. That is absolute killer for the future maintenance and must be refactored asap. Then you can search for the places where you have a lot of if-else conditions and you might assume that this will be changed very often in the future (to add additional if-else clauses). If it so, this should be the next place for refactoring. [more in next comment]

Comment: then you can search for the big methods. If you see that some of the methods are too big, it's time to make it smaller and cleaner by refactoring. When you break them down, you can see whether your class/classes has/have a lot of responsibility. If yes, then try by creating new classes and give them one responsibility. Next step would be if you see a lot of params passed to the method. This might be that the method is on wrong place or needs to introduce some new classes (or maybe implement builder pattern). I hope I helped at least a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

**When business requirements changes and it's hard to incorporate new software behaviour into a codebase, this is a main criteria for refactoring‌*!*** At this moment, it becomes high priority, since it would unblock us to implement desired changes.

> *First make it easy to change, than make an easy change ;)*

**When to refactor:**

- It's hard to make a change — too many places requires modification;
- Arrangement part within a test is way big;
- Code smell(s) presence;
- Implementation has many dependencies;
- Common design pattern could replace a custom solution;
- When source code isn't understandable;

As regarding when **not to refactor**, I'd say probably when writing code for a startup without validated product market fit. Your project could be over shortly, therefore what for to make it technically scalable before making it work.